# How many mapper class instances are created?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

If i hava a mapper class called MAxTemperatureMapper and when i give as input a TextInputFormat class with file with 100 records.
IS the number of mapper instances created equal to number of input splits or is a new mapper created for each key value pair in the input.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Number of mapper would be equal to number of input splits .

when ever you submit a job ,first of all it determines number of splits ,splits are logical .

usually one split size is equal to hdfs block size but that can also be configured where your split size could be less than or greater than block size . for efficent processing usually one split size is equal to block size .

suppose you  have file of 1 GB ,your default block size is 128 mb so approximately you will have 8  blocks and 8 input splits would be required and hence 8 mappers would be invoked for this process .
```